# Imprimir PDF pelo Firefox

Tags: javascript, pdf

Estou usando o seguinte comando para mandar imprimir um PDF que está dentro de iFrame, e o PDF está inclusive local, no mesmo servidor:

```
window.frames["imprimirpdf"].focus();
window.frames["imprimirpdf"].print();
```

Quando mando imprimir pelo Google Chrome funciona corretamente, quando mando pelo Firefox apresenta a seguinte mensagem: **Error: Permission denied to access property 'print'**

Alguém sabe como resolver isso ou como fazer para funcionar no Firefox?

Answer (score 1):

Caio,

Existe um bug antigo (https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=911444)
no plugin interno de pdf do firefox, e não foi resolvido até a data dessa postagem.

Comment: e não existe uma forma simples de resolver?

Comment: até o momento no projeto que precisei de usar isso, não dá pra usar frames(pra isso), por isso nenhum dos bancos brasileiros usam, sempre abre uma "nova aba"(vulgo popup) pra você imprimir o boleto pra pagamento.